# Gridview ItemTemplate Checkbox to Check Based On Sql Numeric Feild

Tags: c#, asp.net

I Have a nested grid i want to check the column in grid when datakey is present in another table

Grid is like this

```
<asp:GridView Width="100%" DataKeyNames="PK_ServiceTypeID" HorizontalAlign="Center" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="gridServiceLocations_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ID="gridServiceLocations" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4">
 <Columns>
  <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <asp:CheckBox runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
   <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
   <img alt="" style="cursor: pointer" src="../../Images/plus.png" />
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlOrders" runat="server" Style="display: none">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvOrders" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="100%" DataKeyNames="PK_ServiceDetailID">
   <Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox runat="server" />
   </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Service" HeaderText="Service" />
    </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
   </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
 <asp:BoundField DataField="ServiceTypeName" HeaderText="ServiceTypeName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
     </Columns>
     </asp:GridView>
```

i have binded this grid from code behind

Comment: You can use the OnRowDataBound event to simply do that.

Comment: Yes you are right but i have values in sql column like this way 0000000062,0000000034,0000000016,0000000174,0000000055

Comment: And where is the problem ? You said you need the check the dataKey , check it in the OnRowDataBound  event and check your checkbox in the needed rows no ?

Comment: The values which am trying to fetch that values are in another table in single column with commas i want to separate that values and if the the value is present in datakeys check box to be check - Thank you for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand I think something like that will be working :

First, you'll need clear data to work with : get the value from your sql column and store it into a string ( or any type you want) array or List, something like that :

```
       //Get your column value from your db
        string myValueFromDb = "0000000062,0000000034,0000000016,0000000174,0000000055";
        //Split the values into an list of string
        myValues = new List<string>(myValueFromDb.Split(','));

       //Here you have all your db values stored in the list myValues
```

But to access to your checkBox you must add an ID.
Like : `asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="checkBox" />`

Now you'll need to check every row of your gridview. Something like that :

```
protected void gridServiceLocations_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && e.Row.RowIndex != -1)
        {

            //Get the value of the current row DataKey
           string dataKey = grid_view.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();

            //GET THE ROW
            GridViewRow row = e.Row;

            //Now compare it with your value
            if (myValues.Contains(dataKey))
            {
                //CHECK CASE
                //The index of column of the column where the checkbox are (1 here, change it )
                CheckBox checkbox = ((CheckBox)row.Cells[1].FindControl("checkBox"));
                checkbox.Checked = true;

            }
            else
            {
                //UNCHECK CASE
                CheckBox checkbox = ((CheckBox)row.Cells[1].FindControl("checkBox"));
                checkbox.Checked = false;

            }                
        }
    }
```

Comment: :) Can u help me same procedure for nested grid in this case i have a nested grid but no comma seperated values multiple rows in table  i have  i have same procedure i have used but getting error ....

Comment: Sure, but could you explain the problem better ?  What's the error message etc .. ?

Comment: When am trying to check checkbox in sub grid with subgrid datarowbound am getting this error                             Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Comment: If there's no data the gridview is empty the method may cause this problem. Make a breakpoint in the beginning of the rowdatabound method and look at the `e.Row.RowIndex`.  Look when the bug is, the data in the gridview, the moment etc ..